# print all numbers from zero to the input

Tags: python, python-3.x, typeerror

```
 def func(i):
    numbers=[]
    for x in range(0,i):
        print "At the top x is %d" %x
        numbers.append(x)
        x=x+1
        print "At the bottom x is %d" %x

    print "The numbers:"
    for i in numbers:
        print i

print "I'm going to print the numbers!"
i=raw_input("Enter the number: ")
func(i)
```

I'm using python 3.0 and using textwrangler and terminal to code. The code is supposed to print all numbers from zero to the input.

Comment: That's not even python-3.x

Comment: That's not even a question.

Comment: 1. not a question. 2. provided info not correct(not python 3).

Answer (score 1):

> I'm using python 3.0

Check again. Because the code you show is obviously Python 2.x

To make the code work in Python 3.x, you need to make some modifications:

- `print` is a function.
- `raw_input` was renamed to `input`

And that leads to your mistake. The return value of `raw_input` (or `input` in Python 3.x) is a string, while you expect an integer in `range(0,i)`. You need to use `int` to convert it.

Answer (score -1):

First the value you take as user input must be int because you want to print numbers. And secondly, raw_input() doesn't work on python 3.5.2, so I've used input(). The code below is okay with python 3.5.2. Try it out.

```
    def func(i):
   numbers=[]
   for x in range(0, i):
       print ("At the TOP x is %d" %x)
       numbers.append(x)
       x=x+1
       print ("At the bottom x is %d" %x)

   print ("The numbers:")
   for i in numbers:
       print (i)

print ("I'm going to print the numbers!")
i = int(input("Enter the number: "))
func(i)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try using this
`print(*list(range(int(input())),sep='')`